# Implement protocol - How to talk with server?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to implement a protocol in Dart.

Basically, I need to create some methods that are similar to `ask_for_help` *(see below)*.

Here is the code I have so far:

```dart
const int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 3;

class MySocket {
  /// The host server
  String _host;

  /// The TCP port number
  int _port;

  /// The status of the socket (connected or not)
  bool _isConnected = false;

  /// The connection timeout
  Duration _timeout;

  /// The connected socket (if any, see [_isConnected])
  Socket _socket;

  /// Establish a connection with the [host] on given [port]
  ///
  /// Throws a [SocketException] if connection cannot be established.
  Future<void> connect(String host, int port,
      {int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT}) async {
    _host = host;
    _port = port;

    _timeout = Duration(seconds: timeout);

    _socket = await Socket.connect(host, port, timeout: _timeout);
    _isConnected = true;

    _socket.listen(default_handler);
  }

  /// Send [cmd] command to the connected server
  void send_request(String cmd) {
    _socket.writeln(cmd);
  }

  /// Close the connection with the server
  void close() {
    _isConnected = false;
    _socket.close();
  }

  void ask_for_help() {
    var cmd = 'HELP';
    send_request(cmd);
    // Start listening to the socket
    // Wait for a response
    // Stop listening to the socket
    // Consume response from the Stream
    // Do something with that response (e.g print it on stdout)
  }
}

void default_handler(Uint8List message) {
  print('----- RESPONSE STARTS HERE -----');
  print(String.fromCharCodes(message).trim());
  print('----- RESPONSE ENDS HERE -----');
}
```

I then have few questions:

1. How can I make `ask_for_help` listen to the socket until it received a response?
2. How to be sure that each method will read the right response and not another one? *(In case multiple requests are sent before the server answer)*

*Remark about 2nd question: With the above code, when I send multiple requests with no delay between them, all the responses came together. This means that I can't tell what function is supposed to handle it.*

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have one service (i.e. `SocketService`) that does the actual communication. When something wants to send a message across the socket, it can call a message. Then expose a stream object that others can subscribe to to listen for messages back.

```dart
class SocketService {
  SocketService _instance;
  SocketService._();
  factory SocketService() {
    if (_instance == null) _instance = SocketService._();
    return _instance;
  }

  final _streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream get stream => _streamController.stream;

  Future init() async {
    // TODO: Initialize the socket connection
    // TODO: Setup incoming messages to get routed to _onMessage
  }

  void _onMessage(dynamic message) {
    _streamController.add(message);
  }

  StreamSubscription listen(void Function(dynamic) onMessage) {
    return stream.listen(onMessage);
  }

  void sendMessage(dynamic message) {
    // TODO: Send the message across the socket connection
  }

  void close() {
    // TODO: Close the socket connection
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

Elsewhere:

```dart
// Listen for incoming messages
var subscription = SocketService().subscribe((msg) {
  print(msg);
});

// Send a message
SocketService().sendMessage('This is a message');
```

The socket-specific stuff will vary depending on which package you use to handle the connection itself. This service class is implemented above as an overly simplistic singleton to get the point across, but you can implement this concept yourself with whatever pattern you want.

On the subcsriber end, you can also utilize a stream transformation to filter out any but the messages you are actually interested in:

```dart
// Filter stream messages so only messages 
// that are string objects get printed
var subscription = SocketService().stream.where((msg) => msg is String).listen(msg) {
  print(msg);
});
```

The filter predicate passed to the `where` method can implement whatever condition you want.

FYI: If you're going to be doing much with streams and stream manipulation, I highly recommend the [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package. It makes working with streams much easier and more intuitive than working with raw streams.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Maybe I did not properly understood it but I don't see how it solves my problem.
To clarify it, I've updated my original post and included the code I wrote so you can better understand what I want to do.

Comment: @Nhqml A socket connection by its nature has messages individualized, so there's no way with the connection alone to tell which response belongs to which message. You're going to have to include some metadata in the message itself that the server retains in its response in order to know where to route the message once your app receives it. Perhaps you can wrap the message in an "envelope" and generate a UUID associated with the message, then in the response you check for the UUID and if it matches, route it to where it needs to go.